# Is possible show data when click a slice of pie chart with canvas-html?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working with pure canvas-html to make a piechart. The slice properties(radius,angles) changes according data. Each slice has an array of objects. I want that when i click on one slice a div with info from the array appears. Is that possible? I read about tooltip but i want to be able to click anywhere inside the slice and show the info in the possition where is clicked.

EDIT: I add how i create the pie and slices, im working canvas as dataClass.
Im trying something like this example: https://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/

```html
   drawSlices() {
        let startAngle = -Math.PI / 2;
        for (const type in this.data) {
            const   changeToNumber = this.data[type].map(elem=>Number(elem.typeCount)), 
                    typeTotal   = changeToNumber.reduce((prev,post)=>prev+post,0), 
                    // eachRadius  = (this.width/3)*typeTotal/this.totalValue + this.width*(25/100), 
                    eachRadius  = (this.width/3 + this.height/3) * typeTotal / this.totalValue +30, 
                    sliceAngle  = (2 * Math.PI * typeTotal) / this.totalValue;
            const   randomColor = this.data[type][0].typeColor;
            this.drawPieSlice(this.width/2,this.height/2,eachRadius,startAngle,startAngle + sliceAngle, randomColor);
            startAngle += sliceAngle;
        }

    }

    drawPieSlice (centerX,centerY,radius,startAngle,endAngle,color){
        this.ctx.fillStyle = `${color}`;
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = `#000`
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        this.ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle); 
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }
```

Comment: share your code in a snippet please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added some part of the dataclass. Im trying something like the example from the link with only js